# Uppercase no funciona en angular

Tags: html5, angular, typescript

Estoy convirtiendo en mayusculas las entras en un `input` en angular con el siguiente evento: `onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"` efectivamente todas las letras cambian a mayusculas en el `input` y hago un cosole.log para corroborar, sin embargo, en la base de datos la ultima letra no me la convierte.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si tenga que ver el orden de los atributos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
addProduct(f: NgForm) {
 console.log("NgForm: ", f)
if (f.invalid) {
  return;
}
console.log(this.product.primerA);   
this.productService.addProducts(this.product);
this.product = {} as Product;

})
```

Comment: listo, agregado

Comment: Genial!!! recuerda siempre agregar tu codigo como texto y no como imagen.. las imagenes son dificiles de ver e indexar

Answer (score 0):

a mi me funcionó de esta manera en el formulario

```
oninput="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"
```